# How to convert List<JsonArray> from vertx to String Array to use in cartesian product

Tags: java, json, api, parsing, vert.x

I have a method that should access data from a json file, basicly an api as shown below, this method accessed the API which is ***www.my-work.com***, next i have accessed the parameters (getConfig method returns a JsonObject).

**What I want to do?** first, convert the parameters to String [] then make a cartesian product using guava before I append the String to the  value of

```
String apiUrl = operator.getConfig().getString("api");
```

My method is,

```
public  ParserService runParserTask(String tourOperator, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> handler) {
                TourOperator operator = TourOperatorFactory.getOperator(tourOperator, vertx, config);
                String apiUrl = operator.getConfig().getString("api");

            operator.getConfig().getJsonArray("parameters").stream().map(o -> {
                List<JsonArray> parameters = ((JsonObject)o).getJsonObject("queryParameters").stream().map(e -> {
                    // TODO int's need to convert JsonArray to String[] and change parameters variable type
                    return (JsonArray)e.getValue();
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());


                // TODO further we'll compact all parameters variants (let's use guava cartesian lib,
                // TODO do not forget to add guava dependency to maven project) and call operator.fetchData(url)
                return null;
            });
            return null;
        }
```

for better understanding the json file below (edited and not full)

```
"operators": {
    "tez" : {
      "api": "www.my-work.com/search/getResult",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "country": "London",
          "queryParameters": {
            "priceMin": ["0"],
            "priceMax":["150000"],
            "currency":["5561"],
          parameters should scroll at the same time 
            "hotelClassId":["4"],
            "accommodationId":["158525","9002884","1","14317","14357", 
               "282471","161160"],
            "rAndBId":["15350","2424","2474","2749","5737","5738"],
            "tourTypes": ["1","2","3","6"],
            "locale":["ru"],
            "cityId":["786"],
            "countryId":["147573"],
```